# making hyperlink of a value stored in table column

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to make the values inserted in `table column($row['survey_name'])` a hyperlink. this is my code which I have tried in php:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{  
     $content .= " 
     <tr id=\"special\" style=\"background:;\"> 
     <td>". $row['survey_name'] . "</td> 
     <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td> 
      </tr> 
      "; 
      ?>
   <script
     $('#special').onclick(function(){window="http://urllinkto.com/x/y/z";})
   </script>
  <?php }//end of while
 if ($content) { 

// See note on the "quote switch" here 
 echo ' 
 <table border= "5" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%"> 
 <tr> 
 <td><strong>Survey Name</strong></td> 
  <td><strong>Date Created</strong></td> 
 /tr>' . 
 $content . ' 
 </table> ';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare variables first.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

$surveyname = $row['survey_name']
$date = $row['date']

$content .= " 
 <tr id=\'special\' style=\"background:;\"> 
 <td><a href='#'>echo $surveyname</a> </td> 
 <td><a href='#'>echo $date</a></td> 
  </tr> 
  ";
}
```

Comment: @user3188226- I have also tried this but it is throwing an error.It is declaring all variables fetched by the query as undefined.

Comment: @user3188226- here is my complete code:                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>N-SURVEY</title>
<meta name="description" content="N-SURVEY" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<link href="/css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <?php include("Afterloginheader.php");

Comment: Rather add your code to your question above, and add your php code, not the html.

Comment: @user3188226- I am unable to copy my whole code here bcoz my code consists most of php but I think the code that I have provided to you is enough to sort out the problem.If you need complete code then tell me sm way to copy whole code here becoz while posting my complete code here I am getting error that my question consist of most of code part,add some more details.

Comment: Where is your $result1 variable declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Chage

```
 <td>". $row['survey_name'] . "</td>
```

to:

```
<td><a href='URL HERE'>". $row['survey_name'] . "</a></td>
```